# Heatmap from pandas dataframe where column and row indices set the grid

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heatmap

I have a dataframe, where the column and row indices represent the x and y values, and the dataframe itself shows the "intensity", already corresponding to the values represented by its column and row indices.

Here is an example.

```py
x = [5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8]
y = [-1 ,0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8]
array = np.random.rand(len(y), len(x))
df = pd.DataFrame(array, index=y, columns=x)
```

[image: dataframe]

This dataframe is already in the desired "heatmap format", in that the grid is specified by the indices and the colormap would be specified by the entries.

However, if I plot this:

```py
plt.imshow(df, cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap]

The axis labels do not correspond to the indices, and it is unclear how they are generated in the first place. Ideally, the x axis would be going from 5 to 8, and the y axis would be going from -1 to 8.

How can I enforce this condition with the heatmap?

Answer (score 0):

imshow has an `extent` argument that holds the min and max of your grid in both axes.

You can read about it [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html#matplotlib-pyplot-imshow) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html#origin-and-extent-in-imshow).